# On-the-fly destructors

Tags: c++, macros

Due to my needing to use C libraries inside C++, I kept finding myself wanting to be able to ensure that the `free` function got called, even if an exception got thrown. `UTILS_SCOPE_EXIT` ensures that the function will be called at the end of scope. External documentation shows how to use it, and also clarifies that it is not allowed to have multiple calls on the same line (because `__COUNTER__` is not always supported):

**utils.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include <functional>

namespace utils { namespace internal {

class ScopeExit_ {
public:
    ScopeExit_(std::function<void()> callback)
        : callback_{ callback }
    {}
    ~ScopeExit_()
    {
        callback_();
    }
private:
    std::function<void()> callback_;
};

#define UTILS_INTERNAL_CAT_HELPER(x, y) x ## y
#define UTILS_INTERNAL_CAT(x, y) UTILS_INTERNAL_CAT_HELPER(x, y)
#define UTILS_SCOPE_EXIT(...) utils::internal::ScopeExit_ UTILS_INTERNAL_CAT(utils_internal_ScopeExit_, __LINE__){ __VA_ARGS__ }

} }
```

This can be used like so:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    UTILS_SCOPE_EXIT([]{ std::cout << "1" << std::endl; });
    UTILS_SCOPE_EXIT([]{ std::cout << "2" << std::endl; });
    UTILS_SCOPE_EXIT([]{ std::cout << "3" << std::endl; });
    std::cout << "4" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "5" << std::endl;
}
```

Outputs:

```
4
5
3
2
1
```

Comment: An alternative (probably safer) is to use actual RAII by wrapping the pointers you have to `free` in a smart pointer with a custom deallocator, e.g. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffb8afb7b5b0b92f

Comment: Yes, use a unique_pointer when you can, with a custom deleter to involve free rather than delete.

Comment: For a general purpose scope exit for things that don't work with the common special classes, you should use a template to capture a lambda rather than std function.

Comment: This is exactly what `std::unique` is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve a better effect using `std::unique_ptr`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// using free1() to prove that the data is being freed.
void free1(void* data)
{
    std::cerr << "Freeing: " << reinterpret_cast<char*>(data) << "\n";
    free(data);
}

void SomeCFunction(char* x);

int main()
{
    // Hold C pointers in std::unique_ptr with an explicit deleter.
    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> holder{nullptr, free1};

    // Then, just reset with new values.
    holder.reset(strdup("Hi"));
    holder.reset(strdup("Bye"));

    SomeCFunction(holder.get());
}
```

Comment: Clarification on why I accepted this answer: I stopped using my `UTILS_SCOPE_EXIT` for pointer management in favor of `std::unique_ptr` and typedefs to avoid template bloat. All other cases where I found myself wanting `UTILS_SCOPE_EXIT` ended up being removed through refactoring. TLDR: I found that my desire for `UTILS_SCOPE_EXIT` was a code smell, and this answer is what helped me realize it.

Comment: Note that unique_ptr's destructor is not called if pointer holds null value

Comment: @yanpas The destructor is always called for automatic objects. Do you mean `free1()` is not called if the pointer is `null`.

Comment: @MartinYork exactly

Answer (score 17):

#### Efficiency

The main issue with `std::function<void()>` is that it is heavy in memory usage. It comes in at a minimum of 32 bytes in G++ and (if memory serves me right) 40 bytes in VC++2015 32-bit.

See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9503ca27f1faded8

#### Solution

Don't use `std::function<void()>`.

---

### A lightweight implementation

I promise you that we can reduce the on-scope-exit object's size to a tiny 1 byte when all we want to do is take an action at the end of a scope by using lambdas and templates.

**Note:** The implementation requires the `<utility>` and `<type_traits>` headers.

**Step 1:** Make a helper function that creates a lambda that calls a callable object.

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
auto make_lambda( F&& f, Args&&... f_args ) noexcept
{
    // important to capture by copy to prevent argument lifetime issues
    return [=] () mutable -> std::result_of_t<F( Args... )>
    {
        return std::forward<F>( f )( std::forward<Args>( args )... );
    };
}
```

- This function creates a lambda that calls the argument callable. We do this so that we can store it for later use; for our use case, in a destructor so that it is called at the end of a scope.
- As of C++14, the `noexcept` specifier is not part of a function's type, so when C++17 comes around and changes that, you'll probably want to come back to this function. See this for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33589752/2296177

**Step 2:** A function to generate the object that calls the stored lambda in its destructor.

```
template<class F>
auto on_scope_exit( F&& f ) noexcept
{
    class unique_scope_exit_t final
    {
    private:
        using fn_t = decltype( make_lambda( std::move( f ) ) );

        fn_t fn_;

    public:
        ~unique_scope_exit_t()
            noexcept( noexcept( fn_() ) )
        {
            fn_(); // call it in our destructor
        }

        unique_scope_exit_t( F&& fn ) // can be extended for complex lambdas
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<fn_t>::value )
            : fn_{ make_lambda( std::move( fn ) ) } // take ownership and store the lambda
        {}

        unique_scope_exit_t( unique_scope_exit_t&& rhs )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<fn_t>::value )
            : fn_{ std::move( rhs.fn_ ) }
        {}

        unique_scope_exit_t( unique_scope_exit_t const& ) = delete;
        unique_scope_exit_t& operator=( unique_scope_exit_t const& ) = delete;
        unique_scope_exit_t& operator=( unique_scope_exit_t&& ) = delete;
    };
    return unique_scope_exit_t{ std::move( f ) }; // we take ownership of argument 'f'
}
```

- Having a class definition that is local to our function allows us to use the deduced type of the template type argument.
- Take advantage of the `<type_traits>` header to make it optimal by declaring everything `noexcept` when possible.
- You can provide a variadic template to the constructor in order to make full usage of `make_lambda()` and so that you can support complex end-of-scope actions. I leave this implementation to you, it is trivial.
- The C++17 standard will guarantee copy elision for the function return.

As promised, one of our objects takes a single byte when its lambda doesn't capture anything. That is:

```
auto test = on_scope_exit( [] { std::cout << "exiting\n"; } );
static_assert( sizeof( decltype( test ) ) == 1, "!" );
```

This is as it implies... the size of our generated object only takes as many bytes as it needs.

We have achieved an implementation that is both flexible and efficient (in speed and size).

### Sample usage

Similar to your usage, however there are no macros involved (personal preference). You can easily wrap this in a macro if it makes you happy.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // remember to store the call's return to prevent it from running early
    auto exit1 = on_scope_exit( [] { std::cout << "1\n"; } );
    auto exit2 = on_scope_exit( [] { std::cout << "2\n"; } );
    auto exit3 = on_scope_exit( [] { std::cout << "3\n"; } );

    std::cout << "4\n";
    std::cout << "5\n";
}
```

Full demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da1afa40ae073523

---

Due to comments.

### Other possible implementations

As noted by [Loki Astari](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/507/loki-astari) and [Nikita Kakuev](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/87094/nikita-kakuev), the previous implementation can increase the executable's size if it is used with many (very many) different types.

In a regular use case, I still think this is a better approach than constantly constructing and destroying 32+ bytes. For example, VC++2015's `std::function<void()>` is 40 bytes in 32-bit mode and 64 bytes in 64-bit mode.

As [Nikita Kakuev](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/87094/nikita-kakuev) points out [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134234/on-the-fly-destructors#comment251237_134241), `make_lambda()`'s signature might be over-generalized for this specific case, so it could be omitted in favour of a more succinct `on_scope_exit()`.

The original thought was that you could make `unique_scope_exit_t`'s constructor take a variadic template in order to allow complex end-of-scope actions by storing callables whose `operator()` have parameters.

If this isn't desired, we can simply remove `make_lambda()` and provide the following implementation of `on_scope_exit()` with a reduced executable size hit:

```
template<class F>
auto on_scope_exit( F&& f )
    noexcept( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<F>::value )
{
    class unique_scope_exit_t final
    {
        F f_;

    public:
        ~unique_scope_exit_t()
            noexcept( noexcept( f_() ) )
        {
            f_();
        }

        explicit unique_scope_exit_t( F&& f )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<F>::value )
            : f_( std::move( f ) )
        {}

        unique_scope_exit_t( unique_scope_exit_t&& rhs )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<F>::value )
            : f_{ std::move( rhs.f_ ) }
        {}

        unique_scope_exit_t( unique_scope_exit_t const& ) = delete;
        unique_scope_exit_t& operator=( unique_scope_exit_t const& ) = delete;
        unique_scope_exit_t& operator=( unique_scope_exit_t&& ) = delete;
    };
    return unique_scope_exit_t{ std::move( f ) };
}
```

This provides semantics similar to a `std::unique_ptr<>` solution while making intent *clear* and keeping size down to what is actually used (`std::unique_ptr<>` does store a pointer of type `T` after all). Usage remains as before.

Comment: Oh! I didn't remember I could define classes inside a function.

Comment: _(if memory serves me right) 40 bytes_ pun intended ? lol

Comment: What is the point of the `make_lambda` function? Why doesn't it work without it? It seems to just construct a lambda which does what the passed in lambda does.

Comment: @Justin the passed in lambda has to be called with arguments, make_lambda creates a no parameter, void return wrapper around the actual lambda. When I said flexible, I meant that you could create closures to be called at the end of scope; these can be of any complexity allowed by a regular lambda. I'll give you a better explanation when I get home, I'm currently at the airport.

Comment: `It comes in at a minimum of 32 bytes`. That's not exactly very heavy in modern day systems. If you have billions around then maybe you would think about it more. Also if you use a templated class then each instantiation of the class will generate its own code. Since each lambda has its own unique type that is potentially one for every lambda. So the extra code you planted could well outway the cost of a `std::function` on some platforms. Note: Note generally disagreeing that I would prefer a template but I don't think that argument holds much weight.

Comment: Now I have not managed to test my above theory. As your code crashes my compiler!! But it would be nice to see how much the executable grows after each call to `on_scope_exit()`

Comment: @LokiAstari Maybe so! However, there's no reason to use up 32 bytes when we can use exactly as many as we need. Furthermore, `std::function<>` will use dynamic memory allocation if his callable is over 32 bytes. That might be rare, but the amount is implementation defined: I believe that Clang is actually the lowest at 24 bytes of available static memory for `std::function<>`. I do agree that executable size might increase, but I'd like to test it. The code compiles under GCC 5.1 with the c++14 flag. I will report back with program size once I get home; thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: I've upvoted this answer for its novelty, but I cannot say that it's anywhere near efficient. Or practical for that matter. Take a moment and look at sizes of generated symbols (`nm -S --size-sort -t d --demangle -S <binary>`). Even a single invocation adds more than 200 bytes of boilerplate code to the binary. And it only gets worse with additional invocations. A bit pricey for saving 31 bytes.

Comment: As for code:
1) Your `make_lambda` is supposed to bind arguments to provided callable. Yet, you never pass arguments to it. Your `on_scope_exit` doesn't take arguments as well.
2) You're capturing supposed arguments by copy in a non-`mutable` lambda (effectively adding `const` to copies) then `std::forward`'ing them using original const qualifiers. Uh-oh.
Get rid of `make_lambda`, it's too broken and makes your code look scary.

Comment: @NikitaKakuev I believe your suggestion is better, I copy pasted that make_lambda from some other stuff I've worked on. I'll change it soon. Thanks for reviewing my review.

Comment: I also think that the main theme of this answer - optimization - is odd, since the speed gain is probably too little to matter for most cases. 32 bytes isn't much, speed gain is also small; honestly, seeking optimization in places like this is(most of the time) a bad idea - you can always improve algorithms. However, the result is quite nice.

Comment: @NikitaKakuev The way I see this being used, unless there are way too many types (emphasis on way too many), the added executable size will be negligible in terms of performance impact. However, depending on his code, repeated allocation and deallocation of 32 or more bytes will add up. I will include a version that generates a smaller executable due to your comment, but is less generalized. The point of haing `make_lambda()` take arguments is that you can configure more complex end-of-scope actions, `on_scope_exit_t` does not need to have arguments, as they are stored in the closure.

Comment: @user2296177 Can you provide some examples of "more-complex end-of-scope actions"? Right now it seems like a premature generalization to me.

Answer (score 4):

## Create wrappers.

If you want to *free* something, you've probably *created* it (or performed some similar operation). UTILS_SCOPE_EXIT solves the problem, but does it solve the right one?

For example, let's say that you have some library XYZ that allows you to create textures like this:

```
XYZ_Texture x = XYZ_Create_Texture(...);
/* code... */
XYZ_Free_Texture(x);
```

UTILS_SCOPE_EXIT *could* help us solve the problem of freeing the texture if we encounter an error, but it doesn't really look nice. We're creating the wrong abstraction.

### The wrapper:

```
class Texture
{
    XYZ_Texture x;

public:
    Texture(...) {x = XYZ_Create_Texture(...);}
    ~Texture() {XYZ_Free_Texture(x);}
    /* other code */
};
```

This way, you can not only go around the limitations of the library, it's also immediately obvious what's going on.

You could also use this approach to create environments - create an object that will call its destructor when scope ends or stack unwinds. The problem with this approach, however, is that if you want to pass some functions - like in your example - this doesn't really work that well(but should you?).

## Use std::unique_ptr

The other option is to use std::unique_ptr. Its template looks like this:

```
template <class T, class Deleter> class unique_ptr<T[], Deleter>;
```

As you can see, there's a Deleter that you can pass as an argument to the template. Quoting cppreference:

> The object is destroyed using a potentially user-supplied deleter by
>   calling Deleter(ptr). The deleter calls the destructor of the object
>   and dispenses the memory.

Therefore, if you think that creating a class is an overkill, you can create a nice pointer that will automatically call the *free* function once it's done.

These are the two approaches that I've used in the past, and they worked well.

Comment: This! Scope Exit is to accomplish one-off *arbitrary* actions: if you find yourself in need to copy/paste your Scope Exit line in multiple functions, you have a problem, if you find yourself using it to handle resources (and thus potentially leak them if you forget it), you have a problem. There's a reason the Scope Exit tool is rarely needed.

Comment: The main problem with making a wrapper class is that I don't want to wrap the 10s of C objects, especially since you have to also write copy constructors, move constructors, assignment operators. But the `unique_ptr` could potentially be used with lambdas, which is a good idea. The only problem with the second approach is when we are managing something other than memory and aren't dealing with pointers

Comment: @Justin if the interface is the same, you could use templates and still go with wrappers. I can understand being lazy, but laziness is sometimes a bad idea. I still don't know your code though, so your approach might be better for this particular case.

Comment: @MatthewRock Templates is a good idea, but you might have `freeMyPointer1()`, `freeMyPointer2()`, and similar functions that aren't quite named the same, so it doesn't work out so nicely. I guess I could take the function itself as a template parameter or a constructor argument... Hmm.